# Keras: how to use predict_generator with classification report in an image classification task with 3 classes.

Tags: image, keras, classification, predict

I am trying to work out how to combine the predict_generator method with Sklearns classification report. Specifically, if my test data is in a folder

```
'test'
```

and there are 3 classes labeled

```
'test/class1'
'test/class2'
'test/class3'

generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/media/simon/HDD/DeepLearning/test',
     target_size=(64, 64),  
     batch_size= 64,
     class_mode="categorical"
     )
```

If I print out the results of

```
probabilities = model.predict_generator(generator, 300)
```

I get an array of probabilities. But I am having great difficulty producing a report with the data structured this way. In particular getting the true labels and setting them in the following code. I am fairly new to Keras.

```
 print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1), predictions.argmax(axis=1),
target_names=["class1", "class2", "class3"]))
```